# How to use IF in SELECT statement as a filter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have simalary (but not identical) report which share the same tables and filters. Instead of writing invidual stored procedures, I'd like to create one and switch between SELECT datasets with a parameter accompanied with a filter.

I've tried something like:

```
IF @UseDataGroup = 1 --from ssrs
    BEGIN
    SELECT
        IF transaction_type IN (10, 27)
        .....
    END
IF @UseDataGroup = 2
    BEGIN
    SELECT
        IF transaction_type IN (11)
        .....
    END

    FROM

    WHERE
```

..with unfortunately returns an error  'multi-part identifier transaction_type could not be bound'
Any help would be aprreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The error is quite clear, `transaction_type` is not recognized.  In addition, `SELECT IF ` is not valid syntax.

Comment: You can use the parameters and the filter on `transaction_type` in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: What's the workaround?

Comment: @NickyvV How? I need to use the procedure for more than 1 report at once.

Comment: @StanislavJirák you can try using the [CASE](http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/sqlserver/understanding-case-expression-in-sql-server-with-example) if you just need to `SELECT` data based on some comparison.

Comment: @Joby I've tried but it still returns the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the incoming filter from SSRS and the filter on `transaction_type` in the `WHERE` clause in your `SELECT` statement

```
SELECT YourFields
FROM YourTable
WHERE (@UseDataGroup = 1 AND transaction_type IN (10, 27))
  OR (@UseDataGroup = 2 AND transaction_type = 11)
  --add additional filters as needed
```

Answer (score 0):

A sample `CASE` statement

```
DECLARE @UseDataGroup INT
DECLARE @transaction_type INT

SET @UseDataGroup = 1
SET @transaction_type = 10

IF @UseDataGroup = 1 --from ssrs
    BEGIN
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN @transaction_type IN (10, 27)
        THEN 'Success'
        END
    END
```

OR

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN @transaction_type IN (10, 27) AND @UseDataGroup = 1
    THEN 'Success'
    END
```

Comment: Just FYI: `CASE` is an expression, not a statement.. ;-)